# Using for loop in Python 3.4 to remove particular element from array

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

As I am new to programming in Python. I am trying to remove particular elements from array using for loop which looks like

```
a=[2,3,1,4,1,1,1,5]
n=a.count(1)
for i in range (len(a)-n):
    if (a[i]==1):
        del a[i]
    else:
        a[i]=a[i]
print (a)
```

I want to remove `1` from array `a`. But, I am getting result as:

```
[2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 5].
```

That is `1` still exists in my new array. Can somebody please answer my problem?

Comment: The answers below show the short & simple way (using a list comprehension). But have you considered you're not looping through all elements, since you subtract `n` from the length of `a`, thus you won't reach all elements in `a`? In your case, you'll only check on the first 5 elements of `a`, not all 9.

Comment: What effect do you think `a[i]=a[i]` would possibly have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try like this:

```
a = [2,3,1,4,1,1,1,5]
a = [x for x in a if x!=1]  # this is called list comprehension
```

note Never modify list while iterating

Answer (score 2):

The real answer to your question (which none of the other answers addresses) is that every time you remove an item, the index `i` moves past it.

in your case:

```
a = [2,3,1,4,1,1,1,5]
```

after deleting the 5th item in the original list, the pointer moves to the 6th item, and the new 5th item (the second `1` in the sequence of three 1s) is skipped.

Regarding the comment *never modify a list in a loop*, try to implement an [in-place algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm) like [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) without modifying the list. *Never* say *never*. *Know what you're doing*.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `while` loop and the `remove` method:

```
a = [2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 5]

while 1 in a:
    a.remove(1)

print a
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually as the [`del`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement) statement will remove elements from your list , and as the list that you bound in your loop doesn't been update after the first deleting you remove incorrect elements from your list , so if you want to use `del` you need to make the list name in your loop to reference to new list , that you can use a function for this aim , but as a more python way you can just use a list comprehension:

```
>>> a=[2,3,1,4,1,1,1,5]
>>> a=[i for i in a if i !=1]
>>> a
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Or you can use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) :

```
>>> a=[2,3,1,4,1,1,1,5]
>>> a=filter(lambda x: x !=1,a)
>>> a
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy `a`  and then remove but you cannot iterate over and delete elements from the same list, if your list starts with `n` elements python will have `n` pointers to each element so removing elements from the list as your are iterating over it will cause elements to be missed.python has no way of knowing you have removed elements from the list:

```
a = [2,3,1,4,1,1,1,5]
for ele in a[:]:
    if ele == 1:
        a.remove(1)
print(a)
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

You can also use reversed which returns and iterator avoiding creating a whole copy of the list at once:

```
a = [2,3,1,4,1,1,1,5]
for  ele in reversed(a):
    if ele == 1:
        a.remove(1)
print(a)
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Or using a list comprehension with the `[:]` syntax so we actually update the original object:

```
a[:] = (ele for ele in a if ele != 1)
```

All the above are linear operations using a single pass over `a`.

Answer (score 0):

The OP changes the list in-place, not creating a new list.

There are two methods, the second is safe, the first might be faster.

```
a = [2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 5]
toremove = 1
for i in range(len(a)-1, -1, -1):
    if a[i] == toremove:
        del a[i]
```

and

```
a = [2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 5]
toremove = 1
for i in range(a.count(toremove)):
    a.remove(toremove)
```

The second removes the element however many times it exists (before the loop).  Since we are not iterating on the list, it is safe to use the `remove` method.

Both fragments should be O(n) (but haven't done the calculations).