# For loop didn't continue

Tags: python

I want to remove the select element in sequence.

For example, I want to remove all 2 in sequence [1,2,3,2,3]

my code is

```
def remove_all(a_list, element):
    for i in range(len(a_list)):
        if element == a_list[i]:
            a_list.remove(element)
            return a_list
```

The output should be [1,3,3]

but the output of my code is [1,3,2,3]

I remove the first 2 but somehow the loop didn't go further to remove second 2. I wonder where is the problem of my code

Comment: I don't think you want to `return a_list` until after the loop is complete. But you also don't want to modify the loop your iterating over while you're iterating over it.

Comment: [Thou Shalt Not Modify A List During Iteration](https://unspecified.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/thou-shalt-not-modify-a-list-during-iteration/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using for loop in Python 3.4 to remove particular element from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28265097/using-for-loop-in-python-3-4-to-remove-particular-element-from-array)

Comment: See also [Python list.remove() skips next element in list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14267722/3890632)

Answer (score 2):

Removing items in-place will almost certainly results in index errors.

```
[x for x in l if x != elem]
```

Answer (score 2):

**2 things.**

- You are modifying a list during iteration, I linked to a good read in my comment. [also here](https://unspecified.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/thou-shalt-not-modify-a-list-during-iteration/)
- You return in the loop thus it stops at the return. Unindent the return, python is all about indentation unlike many other popular languages in this matter.

**Try instead**

- Building another list for return:

  ```
  def remove_all(a_list, element):
      result = []
      for ele in a_list:
          if element != ele:
              result.append(ele)
      return result
  ```
- Using a comprehension:

  ```
  def remove_all(a_list, element):
      return [ele for ele in a_list if ele != element]
  ```

Comment: you forgot to un-indent your first example, and have double returns in the second one

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh Thank you! formatting/pasting issue.

Comment: one thing about the second example is that there is a typo. The alist.copy() should be a_list.copy(). Also, I can't run that function.  I am getting the following error: in remove_all
    del result[i]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: @thecatbehindthemask Thanks, I wrote that after I answered without running. I just removed it.

Answer (score -1):

a possible work-around is:

```
while element in a_list:
    a_list.remove(element)

return element
```

But list comprehension works too, possibly even faster.

Answer (score -1):

You should place the return after the loop finishes, something like:

```
def remove_all(a_list, element):
for i in a_list:
    if element == i:
        a_list.remove(element)
return a_list


a_list = [1, 2, 3, 2, 3]
result = remove_all(a_list, 2)

print(result)
```

**Edit**:
The code above does not work with the [2,2] case as pointed out in the comments.
Another solution would be:

```
myList = [2,2]
myList = list(filter((2).__ne__, myList))
print(myList)
```

Like that you don't copy the list anywhere, just is the list you are working on avoiding a list copy that can be expensive.

The `__ne__` function checks that the element exists in the list returning `True` or `False`.

Comment: same problem as the guy before - this can skip some steps. The other guy (with range(len)) could also get out of range error

Comment: Could you please make an example? I can't see how this can skip some steps. It's directly comparing the list element and the element to erase. What can be skipped?

Comment: super easy: `remove_all([2, 2], 2)`

Comment: I see, the issue is the remove function. I was not expecting that behavior.